# Reversing features after applying log transform, what does it mean and when should i apply it?

Tags: data-cleaning

So, I have a skewness problem in my data (the features not the target var) that I want to feed into a NN. and according to this [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/top-3-methods-for-handling-skewed-data-1334e0debf45) and a few other links, I have quite a few options to deal with it. but some of them mention

> you’ll have to reverse it once when making predictions

I don't understand when making predictions means. does it mean when I do forward prop i should reverse the log transform? or does it mean when making predictions on dev and test set?

And, should i also apply log transform to dev and test set?

Also, if i were to deploy this model, does it mean that I always need to log transform features that i apply log transform while training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to back-transform your features. Just apply the transformations to your features and make your predictions. For instance, if you $\log$ your features during training, so the same in production.

Back-transforming your predictions means that, if you predict the expected value of the $\log$, you need to wrestle with your model to tease out the expected value. However, this only applies when you transform $y$, which you do not.

I’m not convinced that you need to transform the features, but if you know to expect particular relationships, transformations can help. All you have to watch out for is applying the same transformations to your features in production.